# mustache, scroll in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, mustache

I'm using mustache to create tables, it works fine in Chorme, but the scroll doesn't work in IE 11.

```
<script id="tamplate-semple-1" type="text/mustache">
  <table>
  {{#data}}
     <tr>
           <td>{{Index}}</td>
        {{#data}}
          <td>{{.}}</td>
      {{/data}}
  </tr>
  {{/data}}
</table>
```

`var myData = [["0001","ONE"], ["0002", 'TWO"],["0003","THREE"], ["0004", 'FOUR"]];
var semple1Html = Mustache.to_html($('#tamplate-semple-1').html(), myData);`

Does it exist a way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: You do not have `</tr>` ending tag in template

Comment: it was a mistake in the post, it exists in my code. Edited